# to import double quotes with laravel json

Tags: json, laravel, double, quotes

current record;

["ss,bb,nn"]

want to save as follows;

["ss","bb","nn"]

my model;

```
protected $casts = [
    'options' => 'array',
];
```

my controller;

```
$cpoll->options = $request->options;
```

Comment: When you store it, is your `$request->options;` an array? And your DB column of JSON type

Comment: You can use php [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) to parse the string "ss,bb,nn" into an array then push the individual items into a new array of ["ss","bb","nn"]

Comment: Follow this here: https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-mutators#array-and-json-casting

Comment: Yes I do the same things. I convert my model file from protected to array ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use both implode and explode to get result. Assign it to variable and do processing then import

1. remove braces from the array

   ```
    $myString =["ss,bb,nn"];
    $string = implode('', $myString);
   ```
2. explode it using comma(,)

   ```
    $myArray = explode(',', $string );
   ```

So finally code will be

```
                $myString = ["ss,bb,nn"];
                $string  = implode('', $myString);
                $myArray = explode(',', $string);
                return $myArray;
```

Comment: Who gave the minus? Your answer is working perfectly.. Thank you, Mr. Master :)

Comment: I didn't do this. But I'm grateful that you've been answering a question I haven't found in days.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
$data = ["ss,bb,nn"];
$data2 = explode(',',$data[0]);
```

Comment: `str_replace` returns a string, not an array as a result.